# Thermally insulate roof windows

Tags: thermal-insulation

I have two 3 by 4 foot roof windows facing south and want to keep the heat out in summer.
What I did on the hottest days was I opened them a bit and strapped cardboard on top. That way a bit (hot) wind came in but the sunlight stayed out.
Of course there are electric shutters, but I guess they will not last ten years, if at all, in these harsh conditions. In summer you can fry eggs on the roof and in winter it's covered with snow and ice.

My best bet was to permanently glue aluminum foil from emergency rescue blankets onto the glass but I do not know what the best removable glue would for that, since these things will also not last forever, but are cheap....

What is your suggestion here? Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.

## Sun controlling devices

### Effective use of plants.

Deciduous trees can be used very effectively as sun controlling devices. Also trellis with seasonal plants on the wall with the greatest sun exposure can be used to great effect.

[image]

The idea here is to use a plant, to stop the sun's radiation from hitting the house and warming it in the summer, and allowing it to pass in and warm the house and warm up the house.

The following image shows a house in the *southern* hemisphere (Australia), with vines on the *north* side.

[image]

Again the orientation is extremely important. Care needs to be taken with regard the humidity that some plants (especially in the trellis version) can impart.

### Louvres

Another option for sun control devices are louvres.

[image]

Again, the idea is:

- block the sun rays from entering in the midday of summer day
- allow the sun rays to enter on the midday of a summer day.

Comment: I like the louver concept. But I dismissed it since I thought they need to be rotateable, which is difficult.
But a fixed one with the right angle is simple and does the job...
Thanks, I have an option here now!

Answer (score 1):

Home improvement centers have R10 insulating foam boards the come in 2' x 4' (feet) and some are self adhesive.

.

[image: R10 foam board]

.

If you have certain species of birds you need to cover them with plastic sheets tho.

The other alternative is to cover the roof windows with a suspended roof of plywood raised 8 inches from the skylights to allow breeze from the sides wash the heat from the windows.